# Understanding the conjugate of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to understand mathematically what is the conjugate of a complex function, and how to obtain it.
Surprisingly, if I search on google I don't find any useful, **deep** and **complete** answer.

Can you suggest me a book (and it's corresponding chapter) where i can find a deep and clear (undergraduate) explanation about conjugate of complex functions?

Comment: You are not asking the right question.

Answer (score 0):

The conjugate of a complex function $z\mapsto f(z)$ is just the function $z\mapsto\overline{f(z)}$. You obtain it by conjugating every number of the form $f(z)$.

Comment: Let's consider the complex cosine function $\frac{e^{i(x+iy)}+e^{-i(x+ij)}
}{2}$. Since the conjugate of $e^{i(x+iy)}$ is $e^{i(-x+iy)}$, i though that the conjugate of the complex cosine was: $\frac{e^{i(-x+iy)}+e^{-i(-x+ij)}
}{2}$

Comment: And you thought well.

Comment: No man, the conjugate of the complex cosine is presended as : $\frac{e^{i(x-iy)}+e^{-i(x-ij)} }{2}$. I don't understand why....

Comment: And is there any difference between$$e^{i(-x+iy)}+e^{-i(-x+iy)}\text{ and }e^{i(x-iy)}+e^{-i(x-iy)}?$$If there is, I can't spot it.

Comment: In this case no. Because the cosine has its complex exponentials in some sort of  symmetrical displacement. However  $e^{i(x-ij)} \neq e^{i(-x+ij)}$, so i would like to understand what it's the correct way to obtain the conjugate of a complex function

Comment: As I rote in my answer, you obtain it by conjugating every number of the form $f(z)$.